# Cross module searches in SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I am trying to add support to search across modules in SugarCRM. More specially, I would like to add a filter in Contacts search to filter contacts whose account has certain description.

I have consulted various posts such as the following:
http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2011/04/19/howto-add-a-search-field-that-searches-another-module/

However I still failed to accomplish what I need to do.

I have made the following changes to searchdefs.php to add a new field "account_desc" to the advance search panel.

```
        'account_desc' => 
          array (
            'name' => 'account_desc',
            'label' => 'Acct desc',
            'type' => 'name',
            'default' => true,
            'width' => '10%',
          ),
```

Then, I added the query in SearchFields.php

```
    'account_desc'=> array(
        'query_type'=>'default', 
        'operator'=>'subquery',
        'subquery'=>'SELECT contact_id FROM Contacts JOIN accounts_contacts JOIN accounts ON (Contacts.id = contact_id AND accounts.id = account_id) WHERE accounts.description LIKE',
        'db_field' => array(
            'id',
        ),
```

The subquery will output list of contact id whose account has certain description. And then SugarCRM will just match the contact id against this list to get the final output.

Unfortunately, it seems that I am still missing something. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: i don't know if this is the reason, but you don't have to join contacts in the subquery. Try `SELECT AC.contact_id FROM accounts_contacts AC INNER JOIN accounts A ON (contacts.id = AC.contact_id AND A.id = AC.account_id) WHERE A.description LIKE`

Comment: Sorry I haven't checked the status of my question for awhile. Anyways, I tried your solution today and it worked! Thanks you. If you want to repost your comment as a reply, I can mark your answer as solution.